# Surjection of ring homomorphism give surjection of group of units?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A,B$ be commutative rings,
and $f:A\to B$ be ring homomorphism.
Then, we get group homomorphism $f^{*}: A^{*}\to B^{*}$.

When $f$ is surjection, is $f^{*}$ surjection?

Comment: what is $A^*$ and $B^*$

Comment: $A^{*}$ is group of units .　In other words, multiplicative group.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Take $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/5$  the canonical map.